# How can I read data from firestore database in a schedule function?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I'm new to Firebase and I'm blocked on something. Actually, I've some difficulties reading data from a Firestore Database. My code:

```js
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
admin.initializeApp();
const db = admin.firestore();

exports.scheduledFunction = functions.pubsub.schedule("* * * * *").onRun(async () => {
  console.log("start");
  const querySnapshot = await db.collection("Next_callenges").get();
  console.log("Let's see :", querySnapshot);
  return null;
});
```

There is no output except this : "let's see : QuerySnapshot{".

To add some context, the objective behind this code is to get the first data inserted in the first database, add it to a second database and delete it from the first one.

Comment: `let's see : QuerySnapshot{` A query snapshot object is what i would expect from the code you've shown. Are you trying to log the data that's inside the snapshot? The snapshot will have a `.docs` property with each of the documents that matched your query, and each of those has a `.data()` method

Comment: You should follow the examples in the API documentation to iterate the results of the snapshot and see what it contains.  Just printing the snapshot object is not likely to be helpful - you really want to write code to see the document data inside it, if there are even any documents found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others have commented, the output you get is exactly what is expected from your code: since you log `querySnapshot`, you get whatever debug output the `QuerySnapshot` class defines.

If you want to see the data of each document in that query snapshot, you can do:

```
querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
  console.log("Document "+doc.id+":", doc.data());
})
```

Note that this is just using the Firestore API and has nothing to do with the fact that you use Firestore in Cloud Functions. Since Cloud Functions adds quite some complexity to the case, I'd recommend first learning more about the Firestore API in JavaScript by reading its [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data) and following its [codelab](https://firebase.google.com/codelabs/firestore-web).